# Configure Visual Studio Code to use the correct Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

On Visual Studio Code, if I run a Python file, I get `ModuleNotFoundError` error for pretty much every external module.

It appears that VS Code is running Python from the following path:

```
/opt/local/bin/python3.10
```

However, I can run Python files via the terminal with no errors.

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

How do I configure VS Code to use the correct Python interpreter?

Comment: "ctrl+shift+P" and choose "python:select interpreter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short-term solution

Specify an interpreter in VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Possibly fast solution, and might create a mess in the long term.

#### Long-term solution

- Learn to use environments: https://realpython.com/effective-python-environment/
- Use environments in VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Might involve some learning, config and setup, and debugging that, but is less likely to mess up your system in the future.